Is it possible to run VsTest in azure pipelines against pre-installed test project
We have an azure pipeline that deploys candidate releases to a staging server.
When the server update is complete a series of automated tests are then run, this is the current layout.

Now the completion speed for all tasks is not bad but as always the question is can we make it faster. So because these are smoke tests they do not change very often which makes me think instead of the Restore and Build steps can we not simply have a ready built solution installed on Azure so then all we have to do is run the final VsTest step?
We are using VS and Selenium
I have never done it that way before so my questions are. Can it be done? and how please?
Thanks in advance for any help here.

Maybe rentention overrides helps. See there.
